# Android: Display pdf in google doc online

Tags: android

I want to display PDF in my application. I have list fragment and detailed fragment in list I am going to give the URL. Here I am getting error When I give google URL it opens in detailed fragment but if I use http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=pdfurl it shows only loading small part in the top of the fragment I cannot see in a large screen can anyone tell me why this is happening.

please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yea i solved my problem

```
        FrameLayout scroller = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
        WebView web = new WebView(getActivity());

        scroller.addView(web); 
        web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        web.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        web.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        web.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);   
        web.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true); 
        web.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        web.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
        web.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);


        web.loadUrl("https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url=http://iit.qau.edu.pk/books/classes%5B2%5D.pdf");
```

And xml layout is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/titles"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.01"
    class="com.elogic.tutorial.HitTheBooks.FragmentLayout$TitlesFragment" />

 <FrameLayout
     android:id="@+id/details"
     android:layout_width="0px"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_weight="0.09"
     android:background="?android:attr/detailsElementBackground" />

</LinearLayout>
```